# Why has my Wordpress theme disappeared from my Wordpress site?

Tags: theme-options

I purchased the Apex Responsive Wordpress Theme in May 2013 and customised it to build my website. Yesterday when I checked my site it would seem all customisation has gone and it has reverted to some sort of default theme. When I log in to the backend it says it is running the Apex theme, but the customised content has gone. When I look under Appearance > themes my particular theme style is not there. Panicking, it looks terrible! Help!
www.lucyreid.co.uk

Comment: Did you make a child theme or did you just modify the theme? It sounds like you modified the theme then when an update happened it automatically overwrote the old theme. Do you have the site backed up anywhere? Hosting company might have it backed up?

Comment: Many thanks for responding! Oh dear, I'm not very techy, so don't know what you mean about 'child theme'. I don't remember modifying anything. I haven't backed up the site - I'll check with my host.

Comment: It would appear my site is not backed up...

Comment: I tried uploading and installing the theme again but it won't accept it, it says that theme is already installed...

Comment: @Lucy Hi, step one, stop panick. Step 2, can you please provide a link to your website to see what is this default theme you are talking about?

Comment: Hi Jack - still panicking :) My website is www.lucyreid.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you should never modify the code of a theme. You should always create a Child Theme that uses that theme. Info about Child Themes - start here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Whenever a theme is updated by the theme author, it overwrites all of the theme code, including the changes you have made to the code.

A Child Theme, however, uses the 'Parent' theme, then you add additional code (page templates, etc), placing those files in the Child Theme folder. From the above reference:

> A child theme allows you to change small aspects of your site’s appearance yet still preserve your theme’s look and functionality.

Now, with the Child Theme in place, any changes to the parent theme will not affect the additional stuff you added via the Child Theme.

To fix your problem temporarily, assuming you have the modified files locally (on your computer), upload those files to the theme's directory, overwriting the theme's original files.

But, long term, you need to put your modified theme files in a different theme folder, and set them up as a Child Theme. Then you can delete the Parent theme, then reinstall it, then activate your Child Theme.

Comment: Many thanks Rick - so it appears I have ruined my own site...

Comment: I keep hitting return! Anyway, I have the original theme files that I downloaded three years ago - can I not just upload that?

Comment: I found this regarding the Apex theme:
https://meta4creations.ticksy.com/article/4918

Comment: Ahhh, so your apex theme has been overwritten by the other apex theme that is free on WordPress. It sounds like you can get the paid apex back, as they say. Then, if your modified files are gone you may just have to create a child theme and modify that.

Comment: You can copy files, overwriting what is there, but carefully. Unfortunate that the 'apex' theme overwrote the other 'apex' theme.  But learning about Child Themes is a 'good thing' for the future....and this thread might help others.